# How to switch tab without clicking on tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the JS fiddle that contains 4 Tabs, If I click on tab the tab content get changed. 
I need to swap the tabs using only css/style without clicking on the button or any event applied to "tabs-menu"

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ConnectRohitAt/5emanb7y/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab">
        <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sit amet purus urna. Proin dictum fringilla enim, sit amet suscipit dolor dictum in. Maecenas porttitor, est et malesuada congue, ligula elit fermentum massa, sit amet porta odio est at velit. Sed nec turpis neque. Fusce at mi felis, sed interdum tortor. Nullam pretium, est at congue mattis, nibh eros pharetra lectus, nec posuere libero dui consectetur arcu. Quisque convallis facilisis fermentum. Nam tincidunt, diam nec dictum mattis, nunc dolor ultrices ipsum, in mattis justo turpis nec ligula. Curabitur a ante mauris. Integer placerat imperdiet diam, facilisis pretium elit mollis pretium. Sed lobortis, eros non egestas suscipit, dui dui euismod enim, ac ultricies arcu risus at tellus. Donec imperdiet congue ligula, quis vulputate mauris ultrices non. Aliquam rhoncus, arcu a bibendum congue, augue risus tincidunt massa, vel vehicula diam dolor eget felis.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
            <p>Donec semper dictum sem, quis pretium sem malesuada non. Proin venenatis orci vel nisl porta sollicitudin. Pellentesque sit amet massa et orci malesuada facilisis vel vel lectus. Etiam tristique volutpat auctor. Morbi nec massa eget sem ultricies fermentum id ut ligula. Praesent aliquet adipiscing dictum. Suspendisse dignissim dui tortor. Integer faucibus interdum justo, mattis commodo elit tempor id. Quisque ut orci orci, sit amet mattis nulla. Suspendisse quam diam, feugiat at ullamcorper eget, sagittis sed eros. Proin tortor tellus, pulvinar at imperdiet in, egestas sed nisl. Aenean tempor neque ut felis dignissim ac congue felis viverra. </p>

        </div>
        <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
            <p>Duis egestas fermentum ipsum et commodo. Proin bibendum consectetur elit, hendrerit porta mi dictum eu. Vestibulum adipiscing euismod laoreet. Vivamus lobortis tortor a odio consectetur pulvinar. Proin blandit ornare eros dictum fermentum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur laoreet, ante aliquet molestie laoreet, lectus odio fringilla purus, id porttitor erat velit vitae mi. Nullam posuere nunc ut justo sollicitudin interdum. Donec suscipit eros nec leo condimentum fermentum. Nunc quis libero massa. Integer tempus laoreet lectus id interdum. Integer facilisis egestas dui at convallis. Praesent elementum nisl et erat iaculis a blandit ligula mollis. Vestibulum vitae risus dui, nec sagittis arcu. Nullam tortor enim, placerat quis eleifend in, viverra ac lacus. Ut aliquam sapien ut metus hendrerit auctor dapibus justo porta. </p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
            <p>Proin sollicitudin tincidunt quam, in egestas dui tincidunt non. Maecenas tempus condimentum mi, sed convallis tortor iaculis eu. Cras dui dui, tempor quis tempor vitae, ullamcorper in justo. Integer et lorem diam. Quisque consequat lectus eget urna molestie pharetra. Cras risus lectus, lobortis sit amet imperdiet sit amet, eleifend a erat. Suspendisse vel luctus lectus. Sed ac arcu nisi, sit amet ornare tellus. Pellentesque nec augue a nibh pharetra scelerisque quis sit amet felis. Nullam at enim at lacus pretium iaculis sit amet vel nunc. Praesent sapien felis, tincidunt vitae blandit ut, mattis at diam. Suspendisse ac sapien eget eros venenatis tempor quis id odio. Donec lacus leo, tincidunt eget molestie at, pharetra cursus odio. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<input type='submit' value='SET Tab 1 Active '/><br/><br/>
<input type='submit' value='SET Tab 2 Active '/><br/><br/>
<input type='submit' value='SET Tab 3 Active '/><br/><br/>
<input type='submit' value='SET Tab 4 Active '/><br/><br/>
```

How can I change tabs from external button.

**JqueryUsed**

```
var SimpleTabs = function (elem) {
    //get tab objects and store as pane + tab
    var activeTabObject;

    var TabObject = function () {

        var self = this;
        this.tab; //element
        this.pane; //element
        this.setClick = function () {
            $(self.tab).click(function () {
                self.showThisTab();
            });
        };

        this.showThisTab = function () {
            if (self !== activeTabObject) {

                //change the tab page and update the active tab
                $(activeTabObject.pane).removeClass('active-page');
                $(activeTabObject.tab).removeClass('active');
                $(self.pane).addClass('active-page');
                $(self.tab).addClass('active');
                activeTabObject = self;
            }
        };

    };

    $.each(elem.children(), function (id,val){
        var tab = new TabObject();
        tab.tab = val;
        var classString = $(val).attr('class');
        var className = classString.split(' ')[0];
        tab.pane = $('#' + className);
        tab.setClick();
        if (classString.indexOf('active') > -1) {
            activeTabObject = tab;
        }
    });

};
```

Above is the jquery snippet handling the tab switch.

Answer (score 2):

I've moved your code around a bit but it's to make it more readable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $tabsMenu = $('.tabs-menu');
  var tabsMenuLength = $tabsMenu.children().length;
  $tabsMenu.find("a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setCurrentTab(this);
  });

  $('#tab-switch').click(function(e) {
    var nextTabId = ($tabsMenu.find('.current').index() + 1) % tabsMenuLength;
    setCurrentTab($tabsMenu.children()[nextTabId].childNodes[0])
  });
  
  // set initial tab as tab 3 
  setCurrentTab($tabsMenu.children()[2].childNodes[0])
});

function setCurrentTab(tabEl) {
  $(tabEl).parent().addClass("current");
  $(tabEl).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
  var tab = $(tabEl).attr("href");
  $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
  $(tab).fadeIn();
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tabs-menu {
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.tabs-menu li {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
  border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
  border-left: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
}

.tabs-menu li.current {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  z-index: 5;
}

.tabs-menu li a {
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tabs-menu .current a {
  color: #2e7da3;
}

.tab {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d1;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: auto;
}

.tab-content {
  width: 660px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}

#tab-1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-container">
  <ul class="tabs-menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sit amet purus urna. Proin dictum fringilla enim, sit amet suscipit dolor dictum in. Maecenas porttitor, est et malesuada congue, ligula elit fermentum massa, sit amet porta odio est
        at velit. Sed nec turpis neque. Fusce at mi felis, sed interdum tortor. Nullam pretium, est at congue mattis, nibh eros pharetra lectus, nec posuere libero dui consectetur arcu. Quisque convallis facilisis fermentum. Nam tincidunt, diam nec dictum
        mattis, nunc dolor ultrices ipsum, in mattis justo turpis nec ligula. Curabitur a ante mauris. Integer placerat imperdiet diam, facilisis pretium elit mollis pretium. Sed lobortis, eros non egestas suscipit, dui dui euismod enim, ac ultricies
        arcu risus at tellus. Donec imperdiet congue ligula, quis vulputate mauris ultrices non. Aliquam rhoncus, arcu a bibendum congue, augue risus tincidunt massa, vel vehicula diam dolor eget felis.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
      <p>Donec semper dictum sem, quis pretium sem malesuada non. Proin venenatis orci vel nisl porta sollicitudin. Pellentesque sit amet massa et orci malesuada facilisis vel vel lectus. Etiam tristique volutpat auctor. Morbi nec massa eget sem ultricies
        fermentum id ut ligula. Praesent aliquet adipiscing dictum. Suspendisse dignissim dui tortor. Integer faucibus interdum justo, mattis commodo elit tempor id. Quisque ut orci orci, sit amet mattis nulla. Suspendisse quam diam, feugiat at ullamcorper
        eget, sagittis sed eros. Proin tortor tellus, pulvinar at imperdiet in, egestas sed nisl. Aenean tempor neque ut felis dignissim ac congue felis viverra. </p>

    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
      <p>Duis egestas fermentum ipsum et commodo. Proin bibendum consectetur elit, hendrerit porta mi dictum eu. Vestibulum adipiscing euismod laoreet. Vivamus lobortis tortor a odio consectetur pulvinar. Proin blandit ornare eros dictum fermentum. Class
        aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur laoreet, ante aliquet molestie laoreet, lectus odio fringilla purus, id porttitor erat velit vitae mi. Nullam posuere nunc ut justo sollicitudin interdum.
        Donec suscipit eros nec leo condimentum fermentum. Nunc quis libero massa. Integer tempus laoreet lectus id interdum. Integer facilisis egestas dui at convallis. Praesent elementum nisl et erat iaculis a blandit ligula mollis. Vestibulum vitae
        risus dui, nec sagittis arcu. Nullam tortor enim, placerat quis eleifend in, viverra ac lacus. Ut aliquam sapien ut metus hendrerit auctor dapibus justo porta. </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
      <p>Proin sollicitudin tincidunt quam, in egestas dui tincidunt non. Maecenas tempus condimentum mi, sed convallis tortor iaculis eu. Cras dui dui, tempor quis tempor vitae, ullamcorper in justo. Integer et lorem diam. Quisque consequat lectus eget
        urna molestie pharetra. Cras risus lectus, lobortis sit amet imperdiet sit amet, eleifend a erat. Suspendisse vel luctus lectus. Sed ac arcu nisi, sit amet ornare tellus. Pellentesque nec augue a nibh pharetra scelerisque quis sit amet felis.
        Nullam at enim at lacus pretium iaculis sit amet vel nunc. Praesent sapien felis, tincidunt vitae blandit ut, mattis at diam. Suspendisse ac sapien eget eros venenatis tempor quis id odio. Donec lacus leo, tincidunt eget molestie at, pharetra
        cursus odio. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<button id="tab-switch">change tab</button>
```

Comment: @This is perfectly working fine as expected, thanks.

Comment: What If I require the First Tab and content to be selected whenever user click the external button.

Comment: Well, that's why i made a function out of your "tab selector" piece of code, you just have to call "setCurrentTab" with the "a" HTML element in it, that's what's happening when i do `setCurrentTab($tabsMenu.children()[nextTabId].childNodes[0])`, so if you want the first tab, what is currently "nextTabId" should be 0. So it becomes `setCurrentTab($tabsMenu.children()[0].childNodes[0])`. To explain a bit more this line : `$tabsMenu.children()` makes an array out of the $tabsMenu's children elements, & `childNodes` does the same thing, so `[0]` because your "li" contains only a "a" element

Comment: I am trying to use the same, but var tab = $(tabEl).attr("href"); is undefined for me.

Comment: I just edited my original answer with an example of the setCurrentTab function. The call to that function should always be in the `$(document).ready` function callback, so $ (jquery) and $tabsMenu are initialised, maybe that was you problem ?

Comment: @I am using this example in my project but I am unable to create a fiddle for it https://www.cssscript.com/demo/simple-javascript-tabs-library-simple-tab/

Comment: Are you using the jquery-tabs or pure-js-tabs one ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160314/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-and-skornous).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$('.tabs-menu a').mouseover(function(){
   event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();

  });
});
```

Comment: I need this from button that are at the bottom.